# OpencCV: Camera motion detection

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a white board with a black line. I want to find the angle made by the line. I could do this part using background subtraction and Hough line transforms. Even when I rotate the board the angle detected is correct. The problem I face is that if the camera is rotated the value obtained varies. I want to obtain the original angle only even when camera is rotated. What should my approach when the camera is rotated to obtain the original angle?

Comment: When you say the camera is rotated, you mean certain angle? do you know this angle?

Comment: What angle do you want to measure? A line alone does not define an angle. You can determine the angle between two lines, or (e.g.) the angle between the line and the image x-axis. Also, from an image alone, you can't distinguish if the camera rotated, or everything else (which is visible in the camera image).

Comment: @Ivan the camera may be rotated in any angle with its axis fixed. I don't the angle in which the camera is being rotated

Comment: @chtz I want to measure the angle the line makes with the x-axis in the screen. I hope that I can distinguish the camera rotation by the difference in frame recorded from the webcam

Comment: By "the screen" do you mean the image, or the whiteboard? In case of the latter, you can of course try to detect the borders of the whiteboard and from that determine its orientation relative to the camera. Maybe provide some sample images (and manually paint-in which angle you want to determine).